# How to unroll a list comprehension

Tags: python, algorithm, list-comprehension, powerset, loop-unrolling

I have the following code I am trying to understand as I am  new to Python. I understand that the code computes the powerset but the line `subsetlist = [ subset + [item] for subset in result]` is a little hard to understand. How can I break this compounded line to simple for loop for understanding.

```
def powerset(x):
    result = [[]]
    for item in x:
        subsetlist = [ subset + [item] for subset in result]
        result.extend(subsetlist)
    return result
```

This is what I have tried to make it simpler but it does not seem to work. My IDLE just gets stuck and does not print anything.

```
def powerset(x):
    result = [[]]
    for item in x:
        for subset in result:
            result.append(item)
    print(result)
```

Comment: the 'compounded line' is called a list comprehension.

Comment: @0TTT0, thank you. Now I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hint:

You were very close.  Just move the empty list creation inside the second loop.

### Working code:

```
def powerset(x):
    result = [[]]
    for item in x:
        subsetlist = []
        for subset in result:
            subsetlist.append(subset + [item])
        result.extend(subsetlist)
    return result
```

### Output from IDLE:

```
>>> powerset('abc')
[[], ['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did that but the IDLE still does not print anything. Should I be printing outside the first loop?

Comment: I was close. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck.